# Are there blocking issues when calling a REST webservice from a Web API APIController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm working in an environment with a light-weight web application (ASP.NET MVC 4.5), with pretty much all of the actual work being implemented in a separate web service application (ASP.NET Web API).

In nearly all cases, all the web site proper does is deliver pages that make AJAX calls to the web service site. But I have one use case in which a page needs to do an httppost to the main web site, and then have the controller action make a call against the webservice, and wait for a response.

Microsoft has, of course, a how-to page:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

On that page, it says:

> Many of the HttpClient methods are async, because they perform network I/O. In the RunAsync method, I'll show the correct way to invoke those methods asynchronously. It's OK to block the main thread in a console application, but in a GUI application, you should never block the UI thread.

So, the question, is blocking in a Controller Action, while we're waiting for a response from the webservice going to cause a problem?  Yes, it means that the response to the browser is going to be delayed, but that seems inevitable given the circumstances.

My expectation would be that this wouldn't be an issue.  Multiple requests are coming into the web service simultaneously, and that for this one request to block for a bit wouldn't have any unusual impact on overall performance.  But I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you await in your action, you're actually just returning the current thread back to the app's thread pool. So it really won't make much difference if you do your server side stuff synchronously or asynchronously unless you're getting enough requests to exhaust your thread pool.

1. Request comes in and is assigned a free thread from the thread pool (if no thread
       is free then the request will sit and wait until one is free)
2. Web Api creates your controller and executes your action
3. When your action awaits, the thread is returned back to the thread pool
4. When the awaited task is done, a thread is assigned back to the request
5. The action finishes its work and returns or is awaited again which will return 
       the thread back to the thread pool again

With that in mind, it's obvious that you're not holding your api back by executing the action synchronously unless your thread pool is running out of available threads. In that case, the synchronous operation would hold you back because new requests are sitting and waiting to be assigned to a thread. But if it was async, that operation will return it's thread back to the thread pool so the new requests will be taken care of sooner.

Comment: Thanks, not just for answering, but getting me thinking about it in a clearer way.